# A non-intuitive kinematics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, relative-motion

> Ann is sitting on the edge of a carousel that has a radius of $6\ \mathrm{m}$ and is rotating steadily. Bob is standing still on the ground at a point that is $12\ \mathrm{m}$ from the centre of the carousel. At a particular instant, Bob observes Ann moving directly towards him with a speed of $1\ \mathrm{ms^{-1}}$. With what speed does Ann observe bob to be moving at that same moment?

Directly with my intuition I think answer should be $1\ \mathrm{m/s}$ but the hint provided in book says answer is not $1\ \mathrm{m/s}$. I have solution also to this question in my book so do not just give solution but help me make sense why answer should not be $1\ \mathrm{m/s}$.

(correct answer according to book is $\sqrt{3}\ \mathrm{m/s}$)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason velocity is root3 m/s and not 1m/s is that when both body are doing pure translational or rotational motion then V 1/2 = -V 2/1. But in this case the second body is not actually doing a rotation motion but in its frame of reference a component of angular velocity is there just like in the case when 1 and 2 both are performing rotation motion as a rigid body.

Hope that helps

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting mathematical expressions.